# returning color of the piece player

Tags: ocaml

Given the following custom types:

```
 type player = Orange | Red | Blue | White ;;
 type piece = Knight of player | Town of player | City
of player | Road of player | Wool of player |
Brick of player | Lumber of player | Grain of
player | Ore of player ;;
```

All four players pieces are stored in a single piece array. Write functions
`getplayer : piece -> player = <fun>`  that given a piece, it returns the
player that owns it.

```
 # getplayer ( Town Orange ) ;;
 - : player = Orange
 # getplayer ( Wool Red ) ;;
 - : player = Red
```

I'm trying to do it in a long way since It's the only one thats working for me. I did try pattern matching and putting for example `| (_ Blue) -> Blue` but I'm getting either two of the errors, value is piece but unit is expected or It's giving a syntax error at `getplayer (Knight Blue);;` at the first bracket when I call the function. I was just wondering if there are any faster ways to do this? Also, when I put first if instruction to return empty bracket if it receives empty brackets, I get an error that the type is wrong.

```
type player = Orange | Red | Blue | White ;;
type piece = Knight of player | Town of player | City
             of player | Road of player | Wool of player |
             Brick of player | Lumber of player | Grain of
               player | Ore of player ;;


let rec getplayer = fun value -> 
  if value = (Knight Orange) then  Orange
  else if value = (Knight Red) then Red
  else if value = (Knight Blue) then Blue
  else if value = (Knight White) then White
    
  else if value = (Town Orange) then  Orange
  else if value = (Town Red) then Red
  else if value = (Town Blue) then Blue
  else  White;;
    
    



getplayer (Knight  Blue) ;;
```

Pattern matching:

```
let rec getplayer = fun value -> match value with
  | (_ Orange) -> Orange
  | (_ Red) -> Red
  | (_ Blue) -> Blue
  | (_ White) -> White;;
    

getplayer (Knight  Blue) ;;
```

When I try to pattern like this, my any value `_` is obviously wrong notated or not placed at the right position since I always get the error

```
Syntax error: ')' expected
  This '(' might be unmatched
```

I wanted to have (anything Color) and then return just that color since the player doesnt realy matter.
I also don't understand how to write the empty piece in a way that If you get () it returns () as well.

Comment: Not a solution, but a suggestion. Every `piece` takes a `player`. It looks like a better pattern _might_ be `type player = Orange | ...` then `type piece_name = Knight | ...` then `type piece = piece_name * player`

Comment: Also... Take a look at [`Association List`](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/List.html#1_Associationlists)... It could help you with an alternate way of implementing the same stuff.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be asking whether there's a faster way to calculate your function. The answer is yes, it's faster to do a pattern match than a series of if tests. OCaml excels at compiling its pattern matches into efficient code.

If you give us an example where you can't get pattern matching to work, we can suggest how to fix it. I don't really want to write your code for you, as this is obviously an assignment.

For your second question, the type of `()` is `unit`. The type of `(Knight  Orange)` (say) is `piece`. They aren't the same type at all. So that's what the compiler is telling you.

**Update**

You're trying to use a pattern of the form `(_ Orange)`. But OCaml patterns don't work like that (as you know). You can't have a wild card for just the value constructor (like `Knight`), since in general the values inside the constructors can be of different types.

Instead of enumerating all the players, you can enumerate all the pieces:

```
let getplayer piece =
    match piece with
    | Knight p
    | Town p
    | City p
    | Road p
    | Wool p
    | Brick p
    | Lumber p
    | Grain p
    | Ore p -> p
```

Since every piece has a player, it might be better to structure them like this:

```
type player = Orange | Red | Blue | White
type piece_t =
    | Knight | Town | City | Road | Wool
    | Brick | Lumber | Grain | Ore
type piece = piece_t * player
```

I.e., you can have a piece represented by a pair.

Then you can write your function like this:

```
let getplayer (piecet, player) = player
```